# Why would my Oauth POST request to Twitter Ads API fail, while the GET request works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I've successfully been able to query the Twitter Ads API with GET requests, but I'm trying to POST (to generate reports) and those keep failing with an UNAUTHROIZED_ACCESS "This request is not properly authenticated" error from Twitter.

I have been able to successfully run the query from Postman, so my credentials are OK.  I have tried a couple of oAuth libraries (the `oauth` and `oauth-1.0a` libraries from npm) and I believe the root cause may be in the way they're generating the oAuth signature in the header.

Here's some test code which shows the problem:

```
    let key = TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY;
    let secret = TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_SECRET_KEY;
    let urlPost = 'https://ads-api.twitter.com/11/stats/jobs/accounts/<<accountid>>?entity=CAMPAIGN&entity_ids=i8be1&granularity=DAY&metric_groups=BILLING,ENGAGEMENT,MEDIA,WEB_CONVERSION&start_time=2022-06-12T00:00:00+10:00&end_time=2022-07-27T00:00:00+10:00&placement=ALL_ON_TWITTER';
    let urlGet = 'https://ads-api.twitter.com/11/stats/jobs/accounts/<<accountid>>';    
    let oauth_token = <<OAUTH TOKEN>>;
    let oauth_token_secret = <<OAUTH TOKEN SECRET>>;

    // METHOD 1
    const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a')

    const oauthConsumer = OAuth({
        consumer: {
            key: key,
            secret: secret
        },
        signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1', 
        hash_function(base_string, key) {
            return crypto
                .createHmac('sha1', key)
                .update(base_string)
                .digest('base64')
        }
    });

    const authHeaderPost = oauthConsumer.toHeader(oauthConsumer.authorize({
        url: urlPost,
        method: 'POST',
    }, {key: oauth_token, secret: oauth_token_secret})); 

    const authHeaderGet = oauthConsumer.toHeader(oauthConsumer.authorize({
        url: urlGet,
        method: 'GET',
    }, {key: oauth_token, secret: oauth_token_secret})); 


    let initialResponse = await fetch(urlGet, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: authHeaderGet["Authorization"]
        })
    });
    console.log(`[TEST] Method 1 GET Received Successful?`, initialResponse.status >= 200 && initialResponse.status <= 299);


    initialResponse = await fetch(urlPost, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: authHeaderPost["Authorization"]
        })
    });
    console.log(`[TEST] Method 1 POST Received Successful?`, initialResponse.status >= 200 && initialResponse.status <= 299);

    
    // METHOD 2
    import oauth from 'oauth'; // This is the npm library "oauth"

    let extra_params = {};
    const oAuthConsumer2 = new oauth.OAuth(
        'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
        key,
        secret,
        '1.0', ``, 'HMAC-SHA1'
    );
    let orderedParametersPost= oAuthConsumer2._prepareParameters(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, "POST", urlPost, extra_params);
    let headerPost = oAuthConsumer2._buildAuthorizationHeaders(orderedParametersPost); 
    let orderedParametersGet= oAuthConsumer2._prepareParameters(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, "GET", urlGet, extra_params);
    let headerGet = oAuthConsumer2._buildAuthorizationHeaders(orderedParametersGet); 


    initialResponse = await fetch(urlGet, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: headerGet
        })
    });
    console.log(`[TEST] Method 2 GET Received Successful?`, initialResponse.status >= 200 && initialResponse.status <= 299);


    initialResponse = await fetch(urlPost, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: headerPost
        })
    });
    console.log(`[TEST] Method 2 POST Received Successful?`, initialResponse.status >= 200 && initialResponse.status <= 299);
    
    console.log(`[TEST ************************************************************************************************************************************************************]`);

    
}
```

The results are that both GET requests work successfully, but both POST requests fail.

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: The problem usually is the sorting of the URL parameters or URL encoding. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature

Answer (score 0):

I believe this appears to be a problem of user identity verification.

You are manipulating identities to deceive your system to produce the desired outcome on your system but the interface verifies identity against its own databases.

This is similar to a nonjudicial hearing officer trying to enter a judgment that requires verification by individual user profile of a judicial hearing officer.

Your workaround does not circumvent the verification standards for the POST function. You may be able to pull data from databases because they may have lower or even no encryption requirements for that function, but you cannot post if your ID is not compliant with the requirements of that function. This prevents unauthorized users from posting to verified accounts.

https://www.okta.com/identity-101/what-is-federated-identity/